# How to find a transformation matrix T?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, control-theory, matrix-equations

(1.) Suppose there is matrix C of dimension "p by n" where p is less then n i.e. p

I want to know is there any particular way exist to find transformation matrix T of dimension "n by n" such that CT=[I_p 0] where "I_p" is identity matrix of dimension "p". As I have studied the transformation matrix "T" will exist if rank(C)=p.

For Eg. Suppose C=[1 0 2;2 3 1] of dimension 2 by 3, here p=2 and n=3 and rank(C)=p=2, then how will we find matrix "T" of dimension "3 by 3" such that CT=[1 0 0;0 1 0]=[I_2 0].

I require the above transformation matrix "T" in control problem for state transformation.

(2.) From my point of view

T can be written as

T=C^{+}[I_p 0]+Y[I_n-C^{+}C]

where "Y" is any arbitrary matrix of dimension "n by n".
C^{+} is right pseudo inverse of C and equivalent to C^{+}=C'(CC')^{-1} where C' is transpose of C.

So if one multiply both sides of above equation with C then get required solution CT=[I_p 0] because CC^{+}=I_p, so above solution gives different values of "T" for different values of "Y" and thus a general solution.

(3.) If I take Y=0 i.e. null matrix then rank(T)is less then n, which I don't want. If I set Y=I_3 then get the required transformation matrix.

(4.) I have studied there is some similarity transformation exist to do above task but I don't have much knowledge about it.

Comment: In general you can reduce the leftmost $n \times n$ block of the matrix to $I_n$, but you cannot force the other columns to 0.

Comment: This is generally possible if (a) you allow two-sided transformations, i.e. matrices $S$ and $T$ applied to the left _and_ right of $T$ (so your transformed matrix will be $SCT$) and (b) your matrix is of full row rank $p$. Otherwise, as JoeyBF mentions, the best you can do is getting the leftmost block to $I_p$ without forcing the part on the right to be $0$ (and even this will not be possible if the rank isn't $p$).